# Accessing data in the json array object

Tags: python, json, parsing, flask

There is an array structure I get as json. I need to access some elements within this array structure.

'assets': [{'asset': 'USDT',

I need to access walletBalance object in it.
How can I do that ?

```
 def account_balance(webhook_data):
     account_data = client.futures_account()
     temp_account_data = json.dumps(account_data)
     test = json.loads(temp_account_data)

     for sym in test:
         print(sym['assets'])
     return account_balance
```

With the above code snippet, the object comes as json, but I can't access the "assets" content

```
{'feeTier': 0, 
'canTrade': True, 
'canDeposit': True, 
'canWithdraw': True, 
'updateTime': 0, 
'totalInitialMargin': '0.00000000', 
'totalMaintMargin': '0.00000000', 
'totalWalletBalance': '32.51609961', 
'totalUnrealizedProfit': '0.00000000', 
'totalMarginBalance': '32.51609961', 
'totalPositionInitialMargin': '0.00000000', 
'totalOpenOrderInitialMargin': '0.00000000', 
'maxWithdrawAmount': '32.51609961', 

'assets': 

[
{'asset': 'USDT', 
'walletBalance': '32.51609961', 
'unrealizedProfit': '0.00000000', 
'marginBalance': '32.51609961', 
'maintMargin': '0.00000000', 
'initialMargin': '0.00000000', 
'positionInitialMargin': '0.00000000', 
'openOrderInitialMargin': '0.00000000', 
'maxWithdrawAmount': '32.51609961'
},

 {'asset': 'BNB', 'walletBalance': '0.00000000', 
'unrealizedProfit': '0.00000000', 'marginBalance': '0.00000000', 
'maintMargin': '0.00000000', 'initialMargin': '0.00000000', 
'positionInitialMargin': '0.00000000', 
'openOrderInitialMargin': '0.00000000',
'maxWithdrawAmount': '0.00000000'}], 



'positions': [
{'symbol': 'EOSUSDT', 'initialMargin': '0', 'maintMargin': '0', 'unrealizedProfit': '0.00000000', 'positionInitialMargin': '0', 'openOrderInitialMargin': '0', 'leverage': '10', 'isolated': False, 'entryPrice': '0.0000', 'maxNotional': '1000000', 'positionSide': 'BOTH'}, 

{'symbol': 'SUSHIUSDT', 'initialMargin': '0', 'maintMargin': '0', 'unrealizedProfit': '0.00000000', 'positionInitialMargin': '0', 'openOrderInitialMargin': '0', 'leverage': '20', 'isolated': False, 'entryPrice': '0.0000', 'maxNotional': '25000', 'positionSide': 'BOTH'}
]}
```

Comment: `test['assets'][0]['walletBalance']`

Comment: thank you so much my friend. it worked, can you write as the answer? Let's confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that there may be multiple asstes, so loop over them:

```
for asset in json_data.get('assets', []):
    print(asset.get('walletBalance'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension

```
res = [x.get('walletBalance') for x in test['assets']]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['32.51609961', '0.00000000']
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are getting a dictionary from the call client.futures_account()
. If So, dumps and loads are not required.
You can simply do:

```
 def account_balance(webhook_data):
     account_data = client.futures_account()
     return [x.get('walletBalance') for x in account_data['assets']]
```